# What is CMSIS in the keil project of TM4C123GH6PZI7 chip? What's the use?

Tags: cmsis, mcu

What is CMSIS in the keil project of TM4C123GH6PZI7 chip? What's the use? And how do you get the project to own this CMSIS?
The same chip, two different engineering templates. The template used has CMSIS, it seems that there is no need to include official library functions. And another template without CMSIS seems to need to add official library functions by itself. So will the CMSIS in the keil project automatically include library functions? So how do I want to have this CMSIS?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egVR0.png)

I asked netizens, and they said that CMSIS is an abstract interface.  In other words, with this interface, as long as you have a chip with a Cortex core and your chip supports CMSIS, you can directly reuse your application layer code.  I don't quite understand what this means?
There is also TI's TM4C123GH6PZI7 chip, is there any graphical tool programming tool? Similar to stm32cubex

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.